# SQL SERVER - Find members of a group that all have the same characteristics

Tags: sql-server-2008

My data agents, that are part of groups.  Each agent can be licensed in multiple states.  I am trying to do a query that takes a client state and checks to see if every agent in a group is licensed in the client state.

Here is sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE GroupAgentState (
GroupID int,
AgentID int,
StateCd CHAR(2) )

INSERT INTO GroupAgentState VALUES
(1,100, 'OH'), 
(1, 100, 'NH'),
(1,100,'NY'),
(1, 101, 'OH'),
(1, 101, 'NY'),
(1, 102, 'NY')
```

I want to do a check so that if I have a Client State (@ClientState) and that client has a relationship with a group, are all agents in the group licensed in the client state?

For my sample data, I would expect that if Client A has a relationship with Group 1 and @ClientState = 'OH', then the return value would be false.  If @ClientState = 'NY', then the return value would be true.

I'm in over my head on this one...

THanks in advance!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

This query shows any agents that are not registered in the Client State:

```
SELECT AgentID
FROM GroupAgentState gas1
WHERE GroupID =  @testGroup
  AND StateCd <> @ClientState
  AND NOT EXISTS( Select *
                  From GroupAgentState gas2
                  Where gas2.StateCd = @ClientState
                    And gas2.GroupID = gas1.GroupID
                    And gas2.AgentID = gas1.AgentID
                 )
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good start for you:

```
-- returns count of agents unlicensed in a particular state (@ClientState) by group
select
    gas.GroupId
    , sum( case when gas.AgentId is null then 1 else 0 end ) UnlicensedAgents
from
    Agent a
    left outer join GroupAgentState gas
     on a.AgentId = gas.AgentId
        and gas.StateCd = @ClientState
group by
    gas.GroupId
```

Comment: Thanks Moho - I was thinking to go thr route of counts, but I was hoping there was a more glamorous solution...